# Is there a way to save a macro in word, not inside the document?

Tags: ms-office

I have created a few macros that I want to apply to several docs.

Every time I open a doc, I have to copy the macro to the document to run it.

Is there a way to store that macro in a global library or something and not inside the document? So, I can call it from there?

Thanks

Comment: Store macros that are not document-specific in your Normal template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Word for the mac when you go to Tools > Macro > record Macro there is a pop-up menu called "Store macro in:" and then "All Documents (Normal.dotm)" is selected.

This will store the Macro in the file that Word checks at startup for macros and will be available to all documents.

In fact all Macro menu selections will have an option for looking in the "Normal.dotm" or saving to "Normal." which is usually the default save location for saved macros.

Answer (score 3):

Macros can be stored in a "global template". The template can be made available to all documents, by putting the template in the Word startup folder.

Or, the template can be loaded for specific documents, via:
Tools>Templates and Add-ins dialog

There's advantages to storing macros in a "global template", instead of in the Normal template.  For instance, macros in the Normal template are available in all Word docs, which might not be wanted.

Word templates are complicated, and they can't be fully explained in a short forum post. The term template refers to a specific Word file-type, and it primarily contains macros, keyboard shortcuts, styles, etc.

Articles on Word templates in MacWord:
[Using Global Templates to add functionality to MacWord](https://wordmvp.com/Mac/GlobalTemplate.html) 
[Other articles on templates.](https://wordmvp.com/Mac/UsingWord-macIndex.html#Templates)

[This article more fully describes template use with macros](https://jimyuill.com/workstation-tools/ms-word/using-templates-from-someone-else.html), but it's for Windows. (To be transparent, I'm the author.)